# Get all nth level elements of dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a list of all nth level elements of a dictionary.

I'd prefer the solution to be generic for the nth item, though my example below lists two levels.

If you imagine the problem as the image below:

[image]

I am trying to get a list of all the values from 16-31.

For example,
I have a dictionary of `i` randomly generated Houses with `j` taps and I need to find out if any of the taps are on.

Is there a way to create a list of all the tap outputs for me to just search through using:

```
for i in list_of_tap_outputs:
    new_list+=lambda x:x[2]
```

or something else or do I have to resign myself to using lists. I'd also like to be able to track which tap was on in the whole system. If I used lists, I'd have to remember which tap was assigned which index in the list and do not want to do that.

```
data={'House'+str(i): {"Tap"+str(j): 'on' if random.randint(1,2)%2==1 else 'off'
                        for j in range(4)} for i in range(3)}

print data
```

with output like this:

```
{'House2': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off', 'Tap2': 'off'},
'House0': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'on', 'Tap2': 'on'},
'House1': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off', 'Tap2': 'on'}}
```

Comment: What would the data look like for an input dictionary of more than two levels? Also please describe in more detail the format of the output you want.

Comment: Does the image I've added help?

Comment: I'm not sure. What will the keys at the intermediate levels be like (although I'm not sure it matters)? I'd like some sample data with more than 2 levels in it to test the code  so I can improve my existing answer.

Comment: Also: Will an nth level exist in every sub-dictionary? If the values a given nth level don't represent taps, when data do you want from it? As far as doing the "nth" level goes, I don't think your question is clear enough nor is the output you want.

Comment: Yes, all intermediate levels would exist. I want a generic way to get all nth level elements in a dictionary without having to recursively do 'for key0,value0 in dict: for key1,value1 in value0: for key2,value2 in value1: .... and so on

Comment: You still haven't described what a multilevel version of the data would have in it exactly. For one level you have `{'House2': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off', 'Tap2': 'off'}, 'House0': {'Tap1': 'off', ...}}`. What would one additional level added to that look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
def any_tap_on(data):
    for house, taps in data.items():
        for tap, status in taps.items():
            if status == 'on':
                return True
    return False
```

Alternately, it could be faster to use the `in` keyword -- as far as order of complexity, it is the same, but builtin operations tend to run faster:

```
def any_tap_on(data):
    for house, taps in data.items():
        if 'on' in taps.values():
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: You’re looking for one of the N taps in M houses so you can’t do anything better than O(NxM).

Comment: You could change the dict to `{'on':{'house1':['t1'...],...},'off':{'house1':['t2'...],...}` to speed up the check for any that are on, but that might slow things down elsewhere

Comment: Is there a more generic solution for the nth item?

Comment: @azaelspeaks I don't know of one without writing a recursive function

Answer (score 2):

Check for any tap on:

```
any('on' in taps.values() for taps in data.values())
```

Check for a particular tap on in any house:

```
any(taps['Tap0'] == 'on' for taps in data.values())
```

You can use `all()` to check for all taps on as well.

Comment: hm, I wasn't aware of `any()`, but that's bound to be better than my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what more than two "levels" would look like, but it's pretty simple for 1 of them:

```
from pprint import pprint
import random

data={'House'+str(i): {"Tap"+str(j): 'on' if random.randint(1,2)%2==1 else 'off'
                        for j in range(4)} for i in range(3)}

def get_nth_level_elements(d):
    results = []
    for key, value in d.items():
        results.append(value)
    return results

results = get_nth_level_elements(data)
pprint(results)
```

Output:

```
[{'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap2': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off'},
 {'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap2': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off'},
 {'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap1': 'on', 'Tap2': 'off', 'Tap3': 'on'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you seem to be asking two questions here, and rather than focusing on the use case with the house and the taps, in this answer, I'll try to address the general case.

I'm no expert on Python implementation details, nor am I familiar with all the builtin functions and standard libraries, but I think the only practical way to generate a list like you are talking about would be by use of a recursive function. You seem to be looking at this problem a lot like a search tree, and you can find plenty of reading on those if you care enough to look into it.

Here's an example function that should do the job. I haven't tested extensively, but it at least works for the sample data you gave.

```
def extract_nth_level(root, n):
    if n == 0:
        return [root]
    values = []
    if isinstance(root, dict):
        for subtree in root.values():
            values += extract_nth_level(subtree, n-1)
    return values

data = {
    'House2': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off', 'Tap2': 'off'},
    'House0': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'on', 'Tap2': 'on'},
    'House1': {'Tap1': 'off', 'Tap0': 'on', 'Tap3': 'off', 'Tap2': 'on'}
}

print extract_nth_level(data, 2)
```

This prints the following list:

```
['off', 'on', 'off', 'off', 'off', 'on', 'on', 'on', 'off', 'on', 'off', 'on']
```